# Como cambiar colores a este tipo de grafico?

Tags: r

Como puedo modificar mi codigo de estos gráficos triangulares para poder cambiarles los colores para poder obtener el gráfico en mejores condiciones, donde dice habitat es una data cualquiera de filas x columnas:

```
library (adespatial)
library (ade4)
library (betapart)
if (require(ade4, quietly = TRUE))
data(habitat)
habitat.pod.J <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = FALSE)
# Sorensen
habitat.pod.S <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = FALSE)
# Ruzicka
habitat.pod.qJ <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = TRUE)
# Percentage difference
habitat.pod.qS <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = TRUE)
# Data frames for the triangular plots
# Data frames for the triangular plots
habitat.pod.J.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.J$D),
habitat.pod.J$repl,
habitat.pod.J$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.J.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.S.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.S$D),
habitat.pod.S$repl,
habitat.pod.S$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.S.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.qJ.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qJ$D),
habitat.pod.qJ$repl,
habitat.pod.qJ$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qJ.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
habitat.pod.qS.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qS$D),
habitat.pod.qS$repl,
habitat.pod.qS$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qS.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.J.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "RichDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "Jaccard similarity", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.S.3[, c(3 ,1 ,2)])
```

Por favor ayudenme como puedo modificarle los colores para que no salga negro y si es posible hacer que salgan con la letra Time New Romann

Comment: ¿Que colores en particular son los que deseas modificar?

Comment: Los del triangulo exterior y la de los puntos interiores

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente `triangle.plot()` tiene muy pocas opciones de customización, sin embargo puedes establecer el color final mediante la función `par()` que es la que se usa para establecer las opciones por d[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]efecto de todas las funciones de graficación base. Por ejemplo:

```
data(euro123)
op <- par(col = "red") # Color por defecto 
plot <- triangle.plot(euro123$in78, clab = 0, cpoi = 2, addmean = TRUE, show = FALSE)
par(op) # Restauramos la configuración inicial
```

Si te resultas muy limitadas las opciones, puede hacer dos cosas:

1. Rehacer la función `triangle.plot()`, son pocas líneas de código y solo habría que agregar customización de color en las llamadas a `points()`, `segments()` y `text()`
2. Ir a [`ggterm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html), que es un gráfica similar pero montada sobre `ggplot2`

Comment: Pero es que no se como hacer este tipo de gráfico con ggtern